# Getting Error in writing a python function based on priorities

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataset of 10k rows in this format:

```
Company_Names     Vaccine_status

Zebraniac au       Done
Zebraniac au       Not Done
Alons gm           In Progress
Endeven Tc         Not Done
Endeven Tc         No Info
```

So, I have to basically write a function to consolidate the duplicate Company names... For example, 'Zebraniac au' has two Vaccine_Status ie. 'Done' and 'Not Done'... So, Only 'Zebraniac au' with 'Done' status will remain in the dataset, and other row of 'Zebraniac au' with 'Not Done' will be deleted, because Done has higher priority than Not Done..

The order of priority is

Done > Not Done > No Info > In progess

Based on these priority, we have to consolidate the rows having same company name...Can someone pls help me out on how to achieve this...I mainly needs a function where I can take this dataset as the input and function returns the dataset with consolidated rows.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Company_Names': ['Zebraniac au', 'Zebraniac au', 'Alons gm', 'Endeven Tc', 'Endeven Tc'],
    'Vaccine_status': ['Done', 'Not Done', 'In Progress', 'Not Done', 'No Info']
})

# Define the priority list
priority = ['Done', 'Not Done', 'No Info', 'In Progress']

# Sort the dataframe by Company_Names and Vaccine_status based on the priority list
df = df.sort_values(by=['Company_Names', 'Vaccine_status'], key=lambda x: x.map({v: i for i, v in enumerate(priority)}))

# Drop duplicates keeping the first row which has the highest priority
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Company_Names', keep='first').set_index('Company_Names')

print(df)

              Vaccine_status
Company_Names               
Zebraniac au            Done
Endeven Tc          Not Done
Alons gm         In Progress
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column for the priority, then groupby the company name and select the columns with the min priority:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Company_Names": [
            "Zebraniac au",
            "Zebraniac au",
            "Alons gm",
            "Endeven Tc",
            "Endeven Tc",
        ],
        "Vaccine_status": ["Done", "Not Done", "In Progress", "Not Done", "No Info"],
    }
)

df["Vaccine_priority"] = df["Vaccine_status"].map(
    {"Done": 1, "Not Done": 2, "No Info": 3, "In Progress": 4}
)

print(df.iloc[df.groupby("Company_Names")["Vaccine_priority"].idxmin()])
```

Output:

```
  Company_Names Vaccine_status  Vaccine_priority
2      Alons gm    In Progress                 4
3    Endeven Tc       Not Done                 2
0  Zebraniac au           Done                 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an ordered [CategoricalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html):

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['In Progress', 'No Info', 'Not Done', 'Done'], ordered=True)

out = (df.astype({'Vaccine_status': cat})
         .sort_values('Vaccine_status', ascending=False)
         .drop_duplicates('Company_Names'))

# OR

out = (df.astype({'Vaccine_status': cat})
         .sort_values('Vaccine_status')
         .drop_duplicates('Company_Names', keep='last'))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Company_Names Vaccine_status
0  Zebraniac au           Done
3    Endeven Tc       Not Done
2      Alons gm    In Progress

>>> df['Vaccine_status'].astype(cat)
0           Done
1       Not Done
2    In Progress
3       Not Done
4        No Info
Name: Vaccine_status, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['In Progress' < 'No Info' < 'Not Done' < 'Done']
#                     PRIORITY ORDER --^
```

More information about how to work with [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html)